# Get Only First Name from Windows Identity

Tags: active-directory, environment, authentication, windows-identity, directoryentry

Is there any way I can get ONLY the first name of a user in WindowsIdentity?
Now I'm getting full name by this code:

```
DirectoryEntry userEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + domain + "/" + userName + ",User");
string fullName = (string)userEntry.Properties["fullname"].Value;
```

But I want to seperate between first name and last name.

(right now I'm using `split(' ')` but there are users with two or more first and last name and I have no way to handel this.)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you switch to the `LDAP:` provider rather than `WinNT:`? As you can see from the list of [unsupported IADsUser properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746507(v=vs.85).aspx) the full user object has `FirstName` and `LastName` but they're not supported for the `WinNT` provider.

Comment: How can I get the properties? You can't just replace `WinNT` with `LDAP` in the path, it gives nothing. Can you write an answer of how to use this?

Answer (score 0):

As I assume that you want different properties for both: First name and last name.
If so then you can use "FirstName" and "Surname" properties for the same.

```
string firstName = (string)userEntry.Properties["firstname"].Value;
string surname = (string)userEntry.Properties["surname"].Value;
```

Hope this helps.!!!